# There is a problem with the hash table using chaining

Tags: c, hashtable

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
   int value;
   struct Hashnode* next;
} Hashnode;

void add(int value);
void print();   

Hashnode Hash[11];

int main() {
   add(12);
   add(44);
   add(13);
   add(88);
   add(23);
   add(94);
   add(11);
   add(39);
   add(20);
   add(16);
   add(5);
   print();
   return 0;
}


void add(int value) {
   int hashIndex = value % 11;

   Hashnode* newNode = (Hashnode*)malloc(sizeof(Hashnode));
   newNode->next = NULL;
   newNode->value = value;


   if (Hash[hashIndex].value == NULL) {   //firstValue
      Hash[hashIndex].next = newNode;

   }
   else {      // if have a value starting chaining
      Hashnode* temp = Hash[hashIndex].next;
      while (temp != NULL) {
         temp = temp->next;
      }
      temp->next = newNode;
   }
}


void print() {
   Hashnode* temp;
   for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
      temp = Hash[i].next;
      while (temp->next != NULL) {
         printf("%d, %d\n", i, temp->value);
         temp = temp->next;
      }
   }
}
```

I made a hash table using chaining, but there is a problem.
If you enter according to the main function and print the result value, the part treated as a collision does not appear.
Please tell me if it's a problem that the input function or print function.

Comment: `Hash[hashIndex].value == NULL` - `value` is not a pointer to be compared to `NULL`. And `0` is probably a valid value.

Comment: Your `print` function is never printing the "first" values, because `temp` is always initialized to `next`

Comment: @Eugene Sh. OK, Let me fix it. Is there any other problem?

Comment: Better to use declare it as `Hashnode *Hash[11];` (possibly with an initializer: `Hashnode *Hash[11] = {0};`). Then you can check if `Hash[hashIndex]` is `NULL` to see if it is unused.

Comment: @Ian Abbott 
Thank you for giving me feedback on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Hashnode{
   int value;
   struct Hashnode* next;
};

void add(int value);
void print();   

struct Hashnode* Hash[11];

int main() {
   add(12);
   add(44);
   add(13);
   add(88);
   add(23);
   add(94);
   add(11);
   add(39);
   add(20);
   add(16);
   add(5);
   print();
   return 0;
}


void add(int value) {
   int hashIndex = value % 11;

   struct Hashnode* newNode = (struct Hashnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct Hashnode));
   newNode->next = NULL;
   newNode->value = value;


   if (Hash[hashIndex] == NULL) {   //firstValue
      Hash[hashIndex] = newNode;
   }
   else {      // if have a value starting chaining
      struct Hashnode* temp = Hash[hashIndex];
      while (temp->next != NULL) {
         temp = temp->next;
      }
      temp->next = newNode;
   }
}


void print() {
   struct Hashnode* temp;
   for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
      temp = Hash[i];
      while (temp != NULL) {
         printf("%d, %d\n", i, temp->value);
         temp = temp->next;
      }
   }
}
```

You must do something like this. Use addresses for storing and not Hashnode as an array. Thanks to `Eugene Sh.` he pointed all your mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for helping me :)
I think the chaining, especially the connection list, was the most problematic part.
Before solving the application problem, I should review it again.